# Syncronous XMLHTTPRequest deprecated crash browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have to read information as below from a microprocessor hardware

```
var save_it = '';
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://www.micro-processor-server/?ROBOT=arm_controle',
    async: false,
    success:function(m) {
      save_it =  m;
    }
  }).responseText;
console.log(save_it);
```

While doing so, it works, but my browser console gives very scary warning as below, also several times I have noticed web-browser Google chrome get hang:

[image]

Can anyone please show an alternative way how to make my Ajax query compatible? (I can't change codes in Micro-processor its third party robot)

Comment: async:true and learn how to use asynchronous code, rather than fear it

Comment: It probably hangs because of network lag because your request is synchronous. It waits for the response and if it takes a long time the browser will pause. Why can't it be asynchronous?

Comment: Just move your logging into the success function and get rid of the async flag... You can also make `save_it` into a local variable within the success callback.

Comment: async:true never worked.

Comment: if i remove the async:true or false it never gets any response at all, but Robot executes the logs in its own terminal, where $.ajax only works when async:false flag is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @YumYumYum: async:true works. You just need to learn how to write async code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code that needs the response in the `success` function. You could also use `$.get` if this is all you're needing to do.

```
$.get('http://www.micro-processor-server/?ROBOT=arm_controle', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

call another function with return data.

```
 $.get('http://www.micro-processor-server/?   ROBOT=arm_controle',function(data){
     myfun(data);
 });

 myfun(data){ 
    console.log(data);//here you might be able get rid of asynchronous behaviour.
 }
```

Comment: You can replace `function(data) {myfun(data);}` with `myfun`, e.g. `$.get('http://www.micro-processor-server/?ROBOT=arm_controle', myfun);`.